# Change BackGround Color of BottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, bottomnavigationview

I'm using Flutter's Nested Navigators plugin https://pub.dev/packages/nested_navigators.

I believe I should be able to change the background color of the `BottomNavigationBar` using `backgroundColor` as a parameter;

```
buildBottomNavigationItem: (key, item, selected) =>
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              item.icon,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            title: Text(
              item.text,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
            ),
          ),
     bottomNavigationBarTheme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
       splashColor: Colors.blue[200],
       primaryColor: Colors.green[300],
       backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      ),
```

But alas, the BottomNavigationBar stubbornly refuses to be anything other than white. Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to replace buildBottomNavigationItem with

```
buildCustomBottomNavigationItem: (key, item, selected) => Container(
         color: Color(0xffb79eb5).withOpacity(.70),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(
                item.icon,
                size: 18,
                color: selected ? Colors.white : Colors.black38,
              ),
              Text(
                item.text,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: selected ? Colors.white : Colors.black38),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```